# In Rust using clippy how can I disable clippy::struct-excessive-bools?

Tags: rust

When I run "cargo clippy -- -W clippy::pedantic" on the code below I get the message:

```
note: `-W clippy::struct-excessive-bools` implied by `-W clippy::pedantic`

help: consider using a state machine or refactoring bools into two-variant enums

help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust clippy/master/index.html#struct_excessive_bool
```

I have tried to disable this with #[allow(clippy::clippy::struct-excessive-bools)] but that fails:

```
5 | #[allow(clippy::clippy::struct-excessive-bools)]
  |                         ^^^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword
```

Is using #[allow(clippy::clippy::pedantic)] the only solution?

'''

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Parser, Default, Debug)]
#[clap(version, about)]
#[allow(clippy::clippy::struct-excessive-bools)]
struct Arguments {
    #[clap(short, long)]
    /// Set aaa
    aaa: bool,

    #[clap(short, long)]
    /// Set bbb
    bbb: bool,

    #[clap(short, long)]
    /// Set ccc
    ccc: bool,

    #[clap(short, long)]
    /// Set ddd
    ddd: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Arguments::parse();
    dbg!(args);
}
```

'''

Comment: I'm curious where did you copy this error from? Running Clippy directly gives the correct lint name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lint is named `clippy::struct_excessive_bools`, with underscores instead of hyphens; and it doesn't need additional namespacing. `#[allow(clippy::struct_excessive_bools)]` [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa6ddc01082dce33915e4b39fc7c3a3f) - run `Clippy` with the "Tools" button at the top-right corner with and without the attribute to see.